# Android Video Editor Library : Add Image, Text, Audio contents in Video file

Tags: android, android-library, android-videoview

I am looking for Android Video Editor Library which allows me to add Image, Text, Audio contents in Video file.
Please share your knowledge if you are aware with this kind of library.
Thanks in advance.